# Update Fragment UI from Service or BroadcastReceiver if Fragment is visible

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-service

**TL;DR**

I need to update a fragment's UI(toggleButton) when it is visible on screen from a running Service.

**Background**

I have a `toggleButton` on a Fragment(named homeFragment). It shows *Stop* text `if(toggleButton.isChecked)`, else it shows *Start* text.
This `toggleButton` starts and stops a Service.

Now, there are two ways to stop this service. One is to tap on `toggleButton` again(which stops the service) and, the other is through Service itself.

When this service is started, `toggleButton` shows 'Stop' text.
This service creates a Sticky Notification and calls `this.stopSelf` after that.
This Notification has a button close this notification. 
This option calls a `BroadcastReceiver` to stop/cancel the notification.

**Problem/Requirement**

Now, when the service is closed through notification button, If app is visible or in the foreground, I want to trigger that `toggleButton` on Fragment to show *Start* text again. 
I don't need to handle this if appActivity is in background/paused/closed (i take care of that through checking `sharedPrefs` in `onCreate()`)

**I tried:**

1. Using a Boolean SharedPref Key(say `isServiceRunning`) which keeps track of service state. In `onCreate()`, I save a `true` boolean. In `onDestoy()`, I save a `false` boolean.
   And then, I register a `onSharedPreferencesChangeListener` to `sharedPrefs(inside fragment)` which checks if `isServiceRunning`'s sharedPrefkey is changed or not. 
   And, if it is, it calls `toggleButton.setChecked(false);`

   This method rarely works. Sometimes it works, sometimes nothing happens.
2. Using a `LocalBroadcastReceiver`, but it has many errors. Like, `can't Instantiate Receiver: no empty method`. I tried to resolve, 
   but figured out that needs a lot of work. And, besides that accessing Fragment views inside another class is just a mess because you have to give them fragment's `layout`
   which can be `null` at any time. Giving this receiver class a `View` element from `onViewCreated()` is difficult. I tried inflating the `layout` + `findViewById` to do this, 
   but no success/error.

   This method never worked, i think it is not efficient.
3. Using `static` variables everywhere. So, i made a global `View` element(say `activeLayout`).
   It is `private` and `static`, so that a `static` method(which toggles the state of `toggleButton`) can access layout of fragment.
   `activeLayout` is assigned a Layout from `onViewCreated()` method.

   Now, if i call this `static` method from my `stopNotificationReceiver`, it works(i only checked two times). But, a new Warning is shown that:

   > **Warning:** Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)

   So, i can't make `activeLayout` as a `static` variable, which breaks this whole idea.

Please suggest me an alternative if i am doing it all wrong. Or correct me on how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a broadcast reciver and register it in your fragment

You can call Broadcast reciver by using below code inside ur service

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("extra", cappello); 
intent.setAction("com.my.app");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your Fragment implement a BroadcastReceiver :

```
private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String state = extras.getString("extra");
    updateView(state);// update your textView in the main layout 
  }
}
```

and register it in onResume() of Fragment:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("com.my.app");
receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: unregister in `onPause()`

Comment: If the fragment is not visible, the broadcastReceiver is not called? Or it is fired but the updates for the UI are just ignored?